# Correct way to cache only some methods of a class with joblib

Tags: python, memoization, joblib

I am writing a class that has some computation-heavy methods and some parameters that the user will want to iteratively tweak and are independent of the computation.

The actual use is for visualization, but here's a cartoon example:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, x, name, mem=None):

        self.x = x
        self.name = name
        if mem is not None:
            self.square = mem.cache(self.square)

    def square(self, x):
        """This is the 'computation heavy' method."""
        return x ** 2

    def report(self):
        """Use the results of the computation and a tweakable parameter."""
        print "Here you go, %s" % self.name
        return self.square(self.x)
```

The basic idea is that the user might want to create many instances of this class with the same `x` but different `name` parameters. I want to allow the user to provide a `joblib.Memory` object that will cache the computation part, so they can "report" to lots of different names without recomputing the squared array each time.

(This is a little weird, I know. The reason the user needs a different class instance for each name is that they'll actually be interacting with an interface function that looks like this.

```
def myfunc(x, name, mem=None):
    theclass = MyClass(x, name, mem)
    theclass.report()
```

But let's ignore that for now).

---

Following the [joblib docs](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/memory.html) I am caching the `square` function with the line `self.square = mem.cache(self.square)`. The problem is that, because `self` will be different for different instances, the array gets recomputed every time even when the argument is the same.

I am guessing that the correct way to handle this is changing the line to

```
self.square = mem.cache(self.square, ignore=["self"])
```

However, are there any drawbacks to this approach? Is there a better way to accomplish the caching?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? Or do we simply follow the docs?

Comment: Now that I think about it, the docs give the generic approach which must allow for the case when invocation of `square` could yield different results _even with same arguments_ on different instances of the `MyClass`. The `square` method as you described would be a `@staticmethod` because it looks like calling the method with same arguments does not change the result. This can be achieved by annotating with `@staticmethod` and making sure the definition does not have `self` as argument, e.g. `@staticmethod #newline def square(x):`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/memory_basic_usage.html#using-joblib-memory-with-a-method),

> If you want to use cache inside a class the recommended pattern is to cache a pure function and use the cached function inside your class.

Since you want memory caching to be optional, I recommend something like this:

```
def square_function(x):
    """This is the 'computation heavy' method."""
    print '    square_function is executing, not using cached result.'
    return x ** 2

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, x, name, mem=None):
        self.x = x
        self.name = name
        if mem is not None:
            self._square_function = mem.cache(square_function)
        else:
            self._square_function = square_function

    def square(self, x):
        return self._square_function(x)

    def report(self):
        print "Here you go, %s" % self.name
        return self.square(self.x)


from tempfile import mkdtemp
cachedir = mkdtemp()

from joblib import Memory
memory = Memory(cachedir=cachedir, verbose=0)

objects = [
    MyClass(42, 'Alice (cache)', memory),
    MyClass(42, 'Bob (cache)', memory),
    MyClass(42, 'Charlie (no cache)')
]

for obj in objects:
    print obj.report()
```

Execution yields:

```
Here you go, Alice (cache)
    square_function is executing, not using cached result.
1764
Here you go, Bob (cache)
1764
Here you go, Charlie (no cache)
    square_function is executing, not using cached result.
1764
```

Comment: This does not work if the method has a call to another method.

Comment: This should still work if `square_function` calls other methods; I've used that pattern many times. There are some subtleties about what triggers joblib to clear the cache when code changes (joblib monitors the body of the cached function for changes and even white space will trigger cache clearing, but joblib does not monitor versions or bodies of dependencies the function may use).